# Is Jesus the Messiah?

Tags: jesus, messiah

Does **Isaiah 7:14** confirm that Jesus is the Messiah, or is there tension with other parts as below.

> Therefore the Lord himself will give you a sign. Behold, the virgin
> shall conceive and bear a son, and shall call his name Immanuel. (ESV)

In **Micah 5:2**, we see that a ruler would come out of the *"house of the loaf" (Bethlehem)*:

> But you, O Bethlehem Ephrathah, who are too little to be among the
> clans of Judah, from you shall come forth for me one who is to be
> ruler in Israel, whose coming forth is from of old, from ancient days. (ESV)

However, according to **many jewish Rabbis**, they argue that he isn't and also, that he didnt't possess the **features of Messiah** in his time, including the fact that he didn't have a biological father, and since the **descendence via tribes is in the lineage of the father**, he couldn't pertain to the **tribe of Judah** (however, according to Isaiah, he had to come from a virgin). Also, in addiction they say that the **Messiah**:

- needs to **rebuild the Temple**;
- needs to **bring all jews to Israel** (and also proclaim the monarchy);
- needs to bring the world in a **state of no wars** (a moment of peace);

Can **Isaiah 7:14** be reconciled?

Comment: I'm not seeing any texts that use the word 'Messiah' here, and this isn't a question about any of the named texts. This feels more like a 'searching for a text' question, which is also off-topic.

Comment: Ask questions about interpreting  individual texts as different questions.  Don't group under one subject.

Comment: I thought it was quite general Perry, you have reason.

Comment: The time has not yet come for the Jews to recognize the Messiah. It will come though. “And I will pour out on the house of David and the inhabitants of Jerusalem a spirit of grace and supplication. They will look on me, the one they have pierced, and they will mourn for him as one mourns for an only child, and grieve bitterly for him as one grieves for a firstborn son.” Zechariah 12:10 (NIV) The temple will be rebuilt, and the Messiah will reign in peace from Jerusalem.

Comment: I agree that is question, in the form that it is, is unsuitable for this site primarily because its focus is on the doubts of some rabbis.  This site is dedicated solely to Bible hermeneutics and does not include debate about others' opinions who are not contributors at this site.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer to this question is simple - either one accepts the entire New Testament and its repeated use of the term "Jesus Christ" (= Jesus the Messiah) or one does not.

I accept that many traditional (non-Christian and non-Messianic) Jews reject both the NT and Jesus as Messiah.  That is their privilege.

However, the entire raison d'etre of the NT is to establish that:

- Jesus came as prophesied
- was born of a virgin
- lived a perfect life
- died according to the Scriptures and prophecies
- was resurrected on the third day
- returned to heaven.

Note the succinct comment of Paul in 1 Cor 15

> **3** For what I received I passed on to you as of first importance: that Christ died for our sins according to the Scriptures, **4** that
> He was buried, that He was raised on the third day according to the
> Scriptures, **5** and that He appeared to Cephas and then to the
> Twelve. **6** After that, He appeared to more than five hundred
> brothers at once, most of whom are still living, though some have
> fallen asleep. **7** Then He appeared to James, then to all the
> apostles. **8** And last of all He appeared to me also, as to one of
> untimely birth.

The great purpose of the New Testament is to demonstrate that Jesus is the Christ or Messiah.  It does this in several ways:

- Jesus is regularly and often called “Christ” or “Messiah” by the inspired writers at least 135 times in the New Testament.
- Jesus is called “Lord” (Kyrios – 1 Cor 5:4, Gal 6:18, Phil 4;23, 1 Thess 1:1, 5:28, 2 Thess 1:1, 2, 12, 2:1, 3:18, Plm 1:25, James 1:1, 2:1, 1 Peter 1:3, etc., about 101 times in NT) the Greek equivalent of “LORD” (Adonai) in the Old Testament used as a euphemism for Jehovah, the Hebrew “Tetragrammaton”.
- Matt 1 and Luke 4 both provide explicit genealogies showing that Jesus is directly descended from Abraham and David, and is thus both King and Priest (as per the NT book of Hebrews), as required for the Messiah.
- The New Testament writers often use the expression, “as it is written”, or, “to fulfil the Scriptures”, or similar, to show that Jesus was the fulfilment of the Old Testament prophecies about the Messiah; eg, Matt 1:22, 2:6, 16, 3:15, 4:14, 8:17, 12:17-21, 13:13-15, 35, 21:4, 41, 42, 26:24, 52-56, 27:8, 9, 35, Mark 1:2, 9:13, 14:21, 49, Luke 3:4, 4:17, 12;14, 24:25-27, 44, 45, John 4:25, 26, 29, 12:38, Acts 2:29, 30, 8:31-34, 18:27, 28, Rom 1:1, 2, 1 Cor 15:3, 4, etc.  (There are many more!)  See Prophecy of Messiah.
- The apostles called Jesus, Messiah and Christ.  John 1:41-45.  See also Peter’s sermon at Pentecost in Act 2; Stephen’s last sermon to the Sanhedrin in Act 7; Apollos’ disputes with Jews in Acts 18:27, 28; Stephen used the great Messianic prophecy of Isa 53 to teach the Ethiopian Eunuch about Jesus as Messiah; all of which were aimed specifically at proving Jesus to be the Messiah and the fulfilment of Old Testament prophecies.
- The entire gospel of John is couched in terms that make Jesus the fulfilment of the entire Old Testament Sanctuary ceremonial system (John 1:1-18).  For example, Jesus is the Lamb of God (John 1:29, 1 Cor 5:7, 1 Peter 1:19), Jesus is the living water (John 4:13, 14), Jesus is the bread of life (John 6:35-51), Jesus is the light of the world (John 8:12), Jesus is the door of the sheepfold (John 10:7-9), Jesus is the good shepherd (John 10:11-14), Jesus is the Resurrection and Life (John 11:25), Jesus is the way, truth and life (John 14:6), Jesus is the true vine (John 15:1-5), etc.

The teaching that Jesus is Christ or Messiah is so important that anyone who denies this is called a liar and antichrist.  1 John 2:22.

I could tabulate about 40 explicit OT prophecies that the NT says were fulfilled by Jesus to prove He was Messiah but space limits me listing all these.

Thus, because I believe the testimony of the NT writers, I am bound to conclude on the basis of the ancient witnesses, that Jesus was indeed, the promised Messiah.

The promised Monarchy of Jesus was fulfilled in the Christian church - Jesus is king of the Christian community, Luke 1:33, John 1:49, Acts 13:23, Rev 11:15.  Compare Jer 33:14-17, Eze 37:22.  Thus, Jesus inherits the Davidic Covenant.  He is also the “Son of David” (Matt 1:1-16) and “Son of God” as predicted in the Davidic Covenant (2 Sam 7); and His kingdom will never be defeated and is eternal, Luke 1:33, Heb 1:8, Rev 11:15, compare Ps 61:7, Isa 9:7, Ps 146:10.

Comment: Actually that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @JoãoVíctorMelo - in what way?  Can you be more specific?  I have addressed the question - how do we know that Jesus is Messiah!

Comment: Actually, it answers this question, but doesn't answer the rabinic questions over this topic, such as needs to bring the world in a state of no wars (a moment of peace);, or if it's necessary to come twice, or even, if the Messiah will come as a servant in the end of times and also as a king just after.

Comment: Hi Dottard - curious as to whether you think this question is on-topic or not. I'm not a fan of single-handedly closing questions, but it seemed fairly clear cut. Interested in your rationale.

Comment: @SteveTaylor - I agree that this is a broad-brush question that is not really the subject a single Bible passage.  I suspected it would be closed but answered it to supply the need of the OP.

Comment: Sure, I appreciate that the site is all about helping people, and I've definitely answered a few questions here and there that I knew were off-topic. But please do Vote to Close any questions you spot like this, and do consider how confusing it can be to newcomers seeing high-rep users like us answering off-topic questions. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you mixing Messiahs? - "Cyrus" | כ֣וֹרֶשׁ Koresh מְשִׁיחוֹ֘ (His-Anointed) rebuilt the temple / returned the exiles to Israel [Isaiah 45:1-2], [Isaiah 44:28], [Ezra 1:1-4] in fulfillment of [Jeremiah 29:14]. — The other Messiah of [Micah 5] is a Davidic King to rule over Israel, restoring Torah observance by removing idol statue worship & destroying oppressors to maintain peaceful Sabbaths for Israel.

What Messianic task (not listed in Tanakh) did Jesus the Nazarene not fulfill? - 2 Maccabees 2 - [verse 7 & 8].

> 2 One finds in the records that the prophet Jeremiah ordered those who were being deported to take some of the fire, as has been mentioned, 2 and that the prophet, after giving them the law, instructed those who were being deported not to forget the commandments of the Lord, or to be led astray in their thoughts on seeing the gold and silver statues and their adornment. 3 And with other similar words he exhorted them that the law should not depart from their hearts.
>
> 4 It was also in the same document that the prophet, having received an oracle, ordered that the tent and the ark should follow with him, and that he went out to the mountain where Moses had gone up and had seen the inheritance of God. 5 Jeremiah came and found a cave-dwelling, and he brought there the tent and the ark and the altar of incense; then he sealed up the entrance. 6 Some of those who followed him came up intending to mark the way, but could not find it.
>
> **7 When Jeremiah learned of it, he rebuked them and declared: “The place shall remain unknown until God gathers his people together again and shows his mercy. 8 Then the Lord will disclose these things, and the glory of the Lord and the cloud will appear, as they were shown in the case of Moses, and as Solomon asked that the place should be specially consecrated.”**

Although the NT established Jesus the Nazarene as the Davidic Messiah from Micah 5, the NT never mentions Jesus revealing the location of the Aron HaBrit (Ark of the Covenant) for the Temple’s restoration.

Comment: most Jews don’t accept 1 or 2 Maccabees as canonical, so how can Jesus fail to fulfil the prophecy in 2 Maccabees if it’s not even in the Tanakh? Is Jesus supposed to fulfil prophecies in the book of Enoch? The book of Tobit? Judith? Also, Jesus did rebuild the Ark. The whole point of the Ark was that in the Ark God’s presence was manifest. Believers in Yeshua understand that God sent His Spirit at Pentecost and now He dwells manifest in all those that trust in Him - THAT is truly the Ark. We are all walking tabernacles of Adonai.